# Android - Two Equal sized Columns GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a GridView with 2 columns. Every Cell has an ImageView. I want that the GridView should be equally divided with 50% of the screen width for each column. Also i need that the ImageView inside the Cell to have the 50% of the screen width which means there should be no white space on the screen available. I have tried but unable to accompolish this. Can anybody let me know how to accompolish this?

Comment: Show some code. what did you try...????